# Is Conda support in artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, conda

I just wonder if conda packages like https://repo.continuum.io

Can be able to mirror from Artifactory?

I tried mirroring it but it was unable to get cache..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Artifactory don't support it natively but you can use this plugin:
[Artifactory Conda User Plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/repository/conda).

You can install it in your Artifactory server (is a groovy file).

Also there are a request to include this funtionality in the future:

[RTFACT-7872 Add support for Conda](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-7872)

Answer (score 2):

A year later and things have changed (as they often do). So adding a new answer.

Artifactory has added support for Conda packages as announced in [this blog](https://jfrog.com/blog/drive-your-data-flow-pipeline-to-production-using-artifactory-conda-repositories/). Here are [the docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Conda+Repositories). Appears this requires Artifactory 6.3+.

Comment: They "support" it but the implementation is not entirely correct. Their indexer does not appear to generate `repodata.json.bz2` files and the `repodata.json` entries omit values from the package indexes including important entries like "noarch". This is preventing us from being able to upgrade to conda 4.6.

Comment: We are also having problems with conda virtual and remote repos. If you just want a local conda channel, you are probably better off sticking with the conda user plugin for now.